# Excel VBA to underline referenced cell data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a string of text in cell A10, which begins with data from Sheet "Input," cell C2. I want the referenced data to be underlined. For example, if "John Smith" was in Input!C2, it should look like "John Smith is having trouble with this formula" with John Smith underlined. Below is the code I have, but it's not working -- it's underlining the entire string of text. Also, while I'm here, how can I get this to run automatically, rather than having to manually run the macro? Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Macro()

With Range("A10")
    .Value = Range("Input!C2") & " is having trouble with this formula"
    .Characters(1, Len(Range("Input!C2"))).Font.Underline = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Should `.Font.Underline` be `xlUnderlineStyleSingle` or `xlUnderlineStyleNone`?

Comment: What do you mean by runnning automatically?

Comment: Look at the helper sub key_in_phrase_helper [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860792/count-and-highlight-keywords-within-phrases/32878493#32878493).

Comment: You need to add Worksheet_Change event on *Input* worksheet and only call the Macro when target includes "C2"

Comment: @PatricK - Actually, *'which begins with data from Sheet "Input," cell C2'* suggests to me that this the result of a formula and may not be able to be done at all.

Comment: drec4s, so cell A10 will update when I change the value of Input!C2

Comment: You need a worksheet_change event sub for the Input worksheet, not the one with john smith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in normal module (assuming the "Contract" is where your `A10` is)...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro()
    Dim sTxt As String
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' Added this
    With Worksheets("Contract").Range("A10")
        .Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        sTxt = Range("Input!C2").Text
        If Len(sTxt) = 0 Then
            .ClearContents
        Else
            .Value = sTxt & " is having trouble with this formula"
            .Characters(1, Len(sTxt)).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True ' Added this
End Sub
```

Then in **Input** worksheet module (updated):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oRng As Range
    Set oRng = Union(Range("B2"), Range("B4"), Range("C2"))
    If Not Intersect(Target, oRng) Is Nothing Then Macro
End Sub
```

**NOTE**
If the `Input!C2` contains formula, you need to *Union* other ranges involved in the `Intersect()` or it won't auto update on their changes.

Alternatively, you can force auto update on the Worksheet calculation, add below to the **Input** worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Macro ' Will not work if Worksheet calculation is Manual
End Sub
```

Screenshots for where the code goes:
[image: Location of Code for Module1]
[image: Location of Code for Input]

Comment: Thanks @PatricK. Definitely on the right track, and I would never gotten this close without your help. I'm running into an error with the Worksheet_Calculate. First, to address a couple things, Sheet1 is Contract, and C2 is a formula, which is =IF(B4>0,CONCATENATE(B2," & ",B4),B2)

Comment: What error you have for `Worksheet_Calculate` event? See updated code for C2's formula.

Comment: Well I had the first set of code in ThisWorkbook instead of a module, so I was receiving a "Sub or function not defined" error. Then I moved it to a module, and it killed my workbook. Excel has completely locked up and I can't seem to recover it yet.

Comment: I just had to disable macros, save as a regular workbook, then save again as a macro enabled workbook to strip that code, because the workbook wouldn't load.

Comment: Make sure you place codes into correct location... screenshots added, Module1 code updated. Try comment out the `Worksheet_Calculate` first.

Comment: It looks like it's working, but when I change the values in the Input worksheet, the debugger pops up and highlights the "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" in the Input sheet.

Comment: Actually I just caught your edit about commenting out the Worksheet_Calculate, and it looks like it's working perfectly

Comment: Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Excellent you got it to work. Remember if `Input!B2`, `Input!B4` has formula, add those range to the union part. Or if you don't want to track this range involvement, just have `Worksheet_Change` to call `Macro` without checking which cells in Input has changed.